# Can I use two different entity managers that point to the same datasource in one transaction?

Tags: spring, jpa, transactions, jta, spring-transactions

I'm using spring with JPA. And I've got two EntityManagers that contain different entities (different modules of one application), and both point to the same datasource.

Can I use both of them in one transaction (using single TransactionManager) ?
Do I have to use JTA for that ? If so what is the best option to use it under tomcat ?

How do I configure it in spring ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both standard JPA transactions and Spring's `JpaTransactionManager` are bound to a single `EntityManager`.  They cannot talk to multiple managers, and so cann't coordinate a transaction across them.

If you need to do this, you either need to merge your entity manager configs so you have just one `EntityManager`, or use JTA transactions (via Spring's JtaTransactionManager).

If you're using Tomcat (which has no out-of-the-box JTA support), then you'll need to find a third party JTA implementation.

Comment: I chose the first option: to merge the entity-managers in runtime. Something like this: http://labs.bsb.com/2010/11/configuring-modular-jpa-applications-with-spring/